# How to view Silverlight traffic in Safari Web Developer?

Tags: safari, web-inspector

I'm running a Silverlight application in my browser. The app communicates to a web server over HTTPS. I want to see the communication between the app and the webserver. Now when I open Web Developer I can see the requests being made. However, when I try to inspect the response from the webserver, a spinner is shown and it stays like that. How can I view the response in Safari 7?

[image: Safari 7 Web Inspector - Response spinner]

Comment: I don't know how to solve your exact problem with Safari, but perhaps side-stepping the issue by using a proxy like Charles would be the most pragmatic way forward?

Comment: @aaaidan I like pragmatic solutions, but I'd also like to understand why my tools don't work as they should.

Comment: Fair enough, this sounds like maybe a bug in Safari. Are you sure that the server's response has ended (and closed the connection?)

Comment: @aaaidan yes, the server closed the connection. In the request overview diagram it is clearly marked as a finished request.

Comment: Could it be that the document type of the response is something that the response preview panel doesn't recognize? Like, if the response was not text/html but JSON or something that the preview doesn't normally render.

Comment: @ChristianCorrea that might be the case as it's an XML document. However why wouldn't it be able to render the XML or JSON as plain text?

Comment: How did you manage to show that response window in the debugger? I am trying to do the same thing but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web Inspector doesn't show network traffic for legacy plug-ins. It is simply not reported to the user interface, which is why you can't see it.

Feel free to file a bug about this at: https://www.webkit.org/new-inspector-bug

Answer (score 7):

I can't understand if your app do a XmlHTTPRequest.

Anyway... in the resource section (red circle in the image) you can find all the information about a request, even its response.

[image: From timeline section you can easily find all the request]

[image: You can access also from resources section]

Hope this will help you! :)

PS: Sorry, my GUI is in italian, but you will understand as well

Comment: Thanks for the response, we're getting close it seems. Although I can see the request (headers and body) and the response headers, there is still no response body. See als [this image](http://i.imgur.com/3jFuRji.png).

Comment: There's no "response data" section? Maybe the response that you are analyze has no body... Could be?

Comment: There's 3.8 kB of response data as can be seen in the screenshot, so that's not the reason either.

Answer (score 3):

If you click on Network Requests (in recording mode) you will see list of all request in the table. If you select a row it is highlighted in the resource section. Clicking on it will show its body.

[image: click on the resource name to see its body]
[image: Showing json body]

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight is a plug in that draws all content outside the DOM so any normal web tools to introspect how a page loads will fail (and in this case, fail without much grace).

You will get similar problems if you try to "debug" a netflix or hulu stream or other streaming content that relies on a plug in as opposed to HTML and CSS and Javascript (for example) to do the rendering.

Answer (score -2):

You can do the following :

1. Safari < Settings < Advanced < "Show Develop in Menu" --> Turn this on.
2. In the Develop Menu bar, choose "Show error console"
3. In the console, select the tab for "Instrument"

In the Instrument toolbox you can see Network Requests and more. That will let you keep track of the requests you want.

Screenshot for reference below :: 
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it doesn't solve my problem. Your instructions show me how to get to the developer menu, but that's not the issue here. The screenshot is taken from the developer menu. My issue is a feature from the developer menu that doesn't appear to work correctly. Namely, inspecting the response from the server. Thanks anyway.